# Regex to Find empty functions in js File using grep

Tags: regex, linux, function, grep

I would like to Find in several files the empty function like

```js
fLocalEvent(){

}
```

I would like to find using grep

I tried:

```sh
grep -Rlz "function fLocalEventoBotoes.*[\n\s]*?}" sob/SOB910C.js
grep -Rlz "fLocalEventoBotoes\((?:(?!\)\s*\{).)*\)\s*\{\s*\}" sob/SOB910C.js - return -bash: !\: event not found
```

Comment: You seem to be using PCRE. Use `grep -P` to switch to this regex dialect.

Comment: grep is a line oriented type of environment. You need a block oriented regex like `Perl` or `Ruby` or `Python` or `awk` to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off using something like `Perl` for this:

```
echo '
fLegit1(x){ something }

empty1(){}

legit2(){ something }

fLocalEvent(){

}' | perl -0777 -lnE 'say $1 while (/(\w+\(\s*\)\s*{\s*})/g)'
```

Prints:

```
empty1(){}
fLocalEvent(){

}
```

With GNU grep, you can use the `-Pzo` switches to use that same regex, ignore line endings, and print only the matched section:

```
echo '
fLegit1(x){ something }

empty1(){}

legit2(){ something }

fLocalEvent(){

}' | grep -Pzo '\w+\(\s*\)\s*{\s*}\s*'

# same output...
```

Answer (score 1):

This grep should work :

```
grep -Poz '\w+\(\){\s*}\n?' data
```

Comment: This will fail with 1) `f( ){ }` or 2) `f(){}`